Torrenting unbearably slow in Deluge
My Deluge client is consistently getting less than 1.0K/s on all torrents it is downloading
There aren't very many peers on each torrent even though the website says >100 on every torrent... Why is the amount of peers significantly less than what they should be?

Have you read The Definitive Guide to Deluge (2024 Update) — RapidSeedbox

@DavidPostill well I’m using a reliable VPN and I’m not sure what else there is that could be causing this issue besides that… It has many of trackers despite this…

There are lots of other setting beside VPN to tweak - go through them all.

@DavidPostill I saw, but none of them apply that I am aware of

@prestonferry I'm glad to hear you solved the issue! You should add your solution as an answer, not in the body of the question :)

Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. Please read Can I answer my own question?

@DavidPostill my apologies Mr David, I thought that was proper... I will avoid making the same mistake next time...
To avoid such mistake again, can you tell me how I can close my answer as solved?

P@prestonferry Read the link just above.
